# jsonpath Array and others at once

Tags: arrays, json, filter, tree, jsonpath

I'm trying to get some of the value from the JSON below.

```
{
    "seq_list":[
    {
        "seq":54582,
        "info_list":[
            {
                "info_seq":28
            },
            {
                "info_seq":29,
                "info_ver":"1.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "seq":54583,
        "info_list":[
            {
                "info_seq":28
            },
            {
                "info_seq":30,
                "info_ver":"1.0.1"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "check":1
}
```

I need only the below values and I should be know this JSON tree information also.

How can I get result as below structure at once ( or similarly) ?

[54852[28,29], 54583[28,30]]

Comment: What do you mean by `[54852[28,29], 54583[28,30]]`? It suppose to be `Array<String>` or maybe `Array<Map<String, Array<Number>>>`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = {
    "seq_list": [{
            "seq": 54582,
            "info_list": [{
                    "info_seq": 28
                },
                {
                    "info_seq": 29,
                    "info_ver": "1.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seq": 54583,
            "info_list": [{
                    "info_seq": 28
                },
                {
                    "info_seq": 30,
                    "info_ver": "1.0.1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "check": 1
}

const res = input["seq_list"].reduce((acc, e) => {
  acc[e["seq"]] = e["info_list"].map(x => x["info_seq"])
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Is it possible use just command? like ...$.svr_list[svr_seq].pb_list[*].pb_seq  ???

Comment: Now I see, from where you want to call it? Terminal, bash script or? What language can you use?